# How to add the GreenSock library to Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, actionscript, gsap

trying to move from FlashBuilder to Intellij IDEA

I am running IntelliJ IDEA v13 and have  a simple Apache Flex project.

I want to add the Greensock actionscript library to run something like:

```
        TweenMax.to(L1, 3, {y: 400});
```

I have included the Greensock AS library under src (src/com/greensock) and have the following:

```
    import com.greensock.TweenMax;
```

No errors or warnings, but no Tween movement from the object (L1).

I have also tries to add the library as a module

(Modules->Dependancies->New Library (src/com/greensock) as a "Raw Actionscript Library",

which results in:

**Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. TweenMax (from /Users/npem/Desktop/logo/src/com/greensock/TweenMax.as) and com.greensock:TweenMax (from /Users/npem/Desktop/logo/src/com/greensock/TweenMax.as) are available.**

But I need the import statement, otherwise I get:

**[logo]: Error code: 1120: Access of undefined property TweenMax.**

So, how do I add the library.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Phil.

Answer (score 0):

The following URL:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Dependencies+Management+%28Build+Path%29

Provided me with the answer (and hopefully others who may have a similar question)

Phil.

Answer (score 0):

First open the Project Settings, (right click on your project then "Open Module Settings" or similar) 
then in that dialo[image]g you should have a Library option on left side like in this image (place the .swc in y= a lib or libs folder near the src folder )